# I need to strip an <em> element of it's italics using javascript. See code

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom

```
<div name="outer">
    <div name="inner">
        <span>The Quick Brown Fox <strong>Jumped Over</strong> The Lazy <em>Dog!</em></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// put your js here! 
document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].textContent = "Cat!";
</script>
```

I would like to keep the same bold styling on the  tag but like to get rid of the italicized. Also, I need to print a message to the console after the javascript has loaded indicating it has loaded correctly. Any help would be great.

Comment: I think you're looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-style property

Comment: A couple of notes: 1. `name` is not a valid attribute for a `div`. You might consider using `class="outer"` and `class="inner"` rather than `name="outer"` and `name="inner"`. 2. You can simplify that code *markedly* by using `querySelector`: `var em = document.querySelector("[name=outer] [name=inner] em");` (or with classes: `var em = document.querySelector(".outer .inner em");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("strong")[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].style.fontWeight = "bold";
document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].style.fontStyle = "initial";
document.getElementsByTagName("em")[0].textContent = "Cat!";

console.log("Here is your message in the console.");
```

You can change the style with the fontStyle attribute. Setting this value to "initial" 
Accepted values are :

- initial
- inherited
- oblique
- normal
- italic

Answer (score 0):

For printing messages to console,

```
console.log(message);
```

For removing the s, use a queryselector and trace from the node, through all the children, til you get to the required element.